# How to use SMB1 on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: samba, 17.04

I recently upgraded one of my two Ubuntu desktop machines to 17.04, and since then my two hardware media players (one of which is quite new) are unable to access the samba shares on that machine. The same players access similar shares on the 16.04 machine without problems. After some investigation I believe that the media players require SMB1 and that has been disabled in 17.04.

Is there a way to keep using SMB1 in Ubuntu 17.04? Or a workaround that will prevent me having to downgrade to 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMB1 has not been disabled in Ubuntu 17.04. If it had other Linux machines would not be able to connect to it - at least not by default. They ( Samba itself not Ubuntu ) are thinking about disabling it but they are not there yet: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1697817

Maybe Samba V5: https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2017-June/121169.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there isn't a way to use smbv1 in Ubuntu 17.04, so I've moved to using NFS shares instead, which seems to work well.